# Webpack chunk loading progress

Tags: webpack

I need to display a progress bar while webpack chunks are loaded from the server.
Is there an easy solution to achieve this? I would expect that some plugin already exists for this, but a quick search on google did not reveal any.

Thanks

Comment: Fantastic question. I know the callback name is, by default, `webpackJsonP`, so you can monkey-patch that to find out when it's completed, but the rest is all internally scoped to webpack's `define` function/module

Comment: Ideally webpack could provide an event API for chunk loading status, but you'd have to take it up with webpack core: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues

Comment: This is one plugin which would work basing on XHR which you could try, https://github.com/seleb/chunk-progress-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 0):

`require.ensure` returns a promise. with this you can indicate whether a chunk has loaded or not:

```js
//entry.js
console.log('loading my chunk...');
let chunkPromise = require.ensure([], () => {
  require('./my-module');
});

chunkPromise
  .then(() => console.log('chunk loaded'))
  .catch(e => console.error('chunk failed to load'));
```